# Problems with admin-ajax.php POST 500 In WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with my WordPress I can't update the product in Quick editing  when click on update button Circle just spins

```
load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-ui-position,utils&ver=4.9.8:4
```

POST `https://novinelc.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500`
in `wp-config`  set php `memory on 256`

Comment: This looks like an internal server error related to line 256 in your wp-config.php file. Check that line for a possible syntax issue.

Comment: If it's not a syntax issue, than you may try increasing the memory limit in that file (say 512)